# php want to send contact form

Tags: php, email

I don't know why it is not working.I want to send contact form to email but when I submit it shows me blank page and no email is send.Here I added the html part too for you to understandable.I hope that I will get a good solution from all experts.Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
  # code...
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $ques_type = $_POST['ques_type'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $formcontent=" From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n Question   Type: $ques_type \n Message: $message";
  $recipient = "backoffice@simarketconsultants.com";
  $subject = "Contact Form";
  $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
  mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
  echo "Thank You!";
 }
?>
```

```
<form methos="POST" action="includes/send-form.php">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="name">Full Name: <sup class="red">*</sup></label>
      <input type="text" class="" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="email">E-mail Address: <sup class="red">*</sup></label>
      <input type="email" class="" name="email" placeholder="example@yourdomain.com" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="phone">Phone Number: </label>
      <input type="tel" class="" name="phone" placeholder="+445678946343">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="ques_type">Question Type: <sup class="red">*</sup></label>
      <select name="ques_type" class="">
        <option for="" id="" class="" selected>Please Select Question Type</option>
        <option for="" name="customers" class="">Customer Sevice</option>
        <option for="" name="new" class="">New Accounts</option>
        <option for="" name="payments" class="">Payments</option>
        <option for="" name="marketing" class="">Marketing</option>
        <option for="" name="partners" class="">Partners</option>
        <option for="" name="technical" class="">Technical Support</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="message" class="adjust">Qusetions or Comments: <sup class="red">*</sup></label>
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your questions/comments will be written here....." required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="btn btn-danger" name="send" value="Send" type="submit">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you close the if condition ? `}`

Comment: Did you check your error.log ?

Comment: Try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your code. You should see `Error!`

PS : it is better to use `PHP_EOL` instead of `"\r\n"` (for cross-compatibility).

Comment: yes I close it its at the end

Comment: Are you working on localhost? Can you also include the HTML?

Comment: I added error_reporting(E_ALL); but nothing

Comment: yes I am working on local host

Comment: Unless you have something like phpmailer installed, php's built in `mail()` function will not work on localhost.

Comment: put 'mail' in if condition & echo 'thanks' in success case & print_r(error_get_last()) in failure..you will be able to understand more..

Comment: hoe can I add the html

Comment: In the very first line of the script add these two lines error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
it will dislay the error if any

Comment: some hosting service has been blocked **mail** function, should you try **phpmailer**

Comment: `<option>` for one thing do not have name attributes but values; only `<select>` holds the name attribute.

Comment: @newuser have you not seen BeatAlex's answer below? there's your answer. I don't know why you're fiddling around with the other answer; you're wasting your time there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your form should say `method='post'` not `methos='post'`.

Secondly, `mail()` doesn't work on localhost. Consider using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or testing on a live server.

Thirdly (is that a word?), make sure that the file that holds the php is in the `includes/send-form.php` file, relative to the file that has the form in.

Last of all, the `select` tags hold the `name` attribute, not the `option`.

Example:

```
<select name='car'>
  <option value='Audi'>Audi</option>
  <option value='Ford'>Ford</option>
  <option value='Skoda' selected>Skoda</option>
</select>
```

```
<?php 

  echo $_POST['car']; //Skoda
```

In your case, that would need to read as:

```
  <select name="ques_type" class="">
    <option value="none_selected" class="" selected>Please Select Question Type</option>
    <option value="customers" class="">Customer Sevice</option>
    <option value="new" class="">New Accounts</option>
    <option value="payments" class="">Payments</option>
    <option value="marketing" class="">Marketing</option>
    <option value="partners" class="">Partners</option>
    <option value="technical" class="">Technical Support</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: good catch, but check their select-option also as I noted in comments ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't close the `<?php` tag. Leave it open, there is no need to close it and  e.g. when you include a file and want to send headers after the include whitespaces behind closing tag would cause an error.

Try to debug like this:

test1:

```
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
  echo 'test';
  exit;
```

Does it output "test"?

Do you have a mailserver installed?

Comment: Debug attemps has to be in comments, not an answer.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\simarketconsultants\includes\send-form.php on line 5

Comment: if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
  echo 'test';
} <-- missed the braceright
  exit;

Comment: their code does have a closing brace. plus the rest of your answer, that shouldn't matter.